# поиск на основе результата предыдущего поиска

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

прошу помочь с реализацией на C#
алгоритм поиска словосочетания следующий

1. нашли все совпадения по первому слову из базы данных
2. по второму == ищем по результатам Первого (Предыдущего) поиска
3. по третьему == ищем по результатам Второго (Предыдущего) поиска
4. по четвертому == ищем по результатам Третьего (Предыдущего) поиска

код страницы Поиска проект MVC5

```
  public ActionResult Asearch(int adStatusId = (int)AdStatuses.Published, bool? isBuy = null, string selectedCategoryIds = null,
                      string selectedTownIds = null, string selectedRegionIds = null, string productName = null, int? page = null)
    {

  #region Получение List<int> categoryIds, townIds, regionIds из строк selectedCategoryIds, selectedTownIds, selectedRegionIds, productName
        List<int> townIds = null;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(selectedTownIds))
        {
            townIds = new List<int>();
            var townIdsParts = selectedTownIds.Split(',');
            foreach (var townIdStr in townIdsParts)
            {
                townIds.Add(Convert.ToInt32(townIdStr));
            }
        }

        var allTowns = TownsDAL.GetTowns();
        var allRegions = RegionsDAL.GetRegions();

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(selectedRegionIds))
        {
            if (townIds == null)
                townIds = new List<int>();

            var regionIdsParts = selectedRegionIds.Split(',');
            foreach (var regionIdStr in regionIdsParts)
            {
                int regionId = Convert.ToInt32(regionIdStr);
                var region = allRegions.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id == regionId);
                if (region != null)
                {
                    var townsInRegion = allTowns.Where(t => t.RegionName == region.Name).ToList();
                    var townIdsForRegion = townsInRegion.Select(t => t.Id).ToList();
                    townIds.AddRange(townIdsForRegion);
                }
            }
        }

        var allCategories = ProductCategoriesDAL.GetCategories();
        List<int> categoryIds = null;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(selectedCategoryIds))
        {
            categoryIds = new List<int>();
            var categoryIdsParts = selectedCategoryIds.Split(',');
            foreach (var categoryIdStr in categoryIdsParts)
            {
                categoryIds.Add(Convert.ToInt32(categoryIdStr));
            }
        }
        #region  поиск по дочерним категориям от выбранных в фильтре категорий (например выбрали Лом и отходы черных металлов, должны найти объявления со "Стальные")          
        AdSearchHelper.ChildCategoriesToAdd(categoryIds, allCategories);
        #endregion
        #endregion

        ///объединенный List<Ad>
        List<Ad> ads = null;// объединенный List<Ad>
        List<Ad> adsAdCategory = null; // список объявлений отобранных на основе поиска по категориям
        string[] wordsProductName; // массив слов [отходы, цветных] из словосочетания (-отходы-цветных-) для поиска
        string adProductName = productName; // переменная для поиска по таблице с продуктами (AdsProduct) по полю полное наименование (Name)
        List<Ad> adsAdProductName = null; // список объявлений отобранных на основе поиска по введенному значению слово или словосочетание для поиска по таблице с продуктами (AdsProduct) по полю полное наименование (Name)
        string[] wordsAdProductName;// массив слов [отходы, цветных] из словосочетания (-отходы-цветных-) для поиска по таблице с продуктами (AdsProduct) по полю полное наименование (Name)

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(productName))
        {
            if (productName.Contains('-'))
            {
                List<int> categoryIdsFromProductName = new List<int>();
                List<int> categoryIdsFromProductNameChild = new List<int>();
                List<int> categoryIdsFromProductNameNext = new List<int>();
                List<int> categoryIdsFromProductCategoryNameNext = new List<int>();
                List<ProductCategory> allCategoriesNext = new List<ProductCategory>();
                // лом-отходы-медных
                wordsProductName = productName.Replace('-', ' ').TrimAndReduce().Split(' '); //Итого получили словосочетание == отходы-цветных Если алгоритм сначала отобрал варианты по первому слову,а потом сортирует этот отбор ещё и по всем остальным словам в словосочетании - это как раз вариант с дефисом.

                int wordCount = wordsProductName.Length;

                IEnumerable<List<int>> enumerable = AdSearchHelper.SearshCategoriesId(wordsProductName, allCategories).ToList();



                #region Search в словосочетании с дефисом То есть он выдаст только те варианты где словосочетание указано целиком в названии Категорий товара лом-отходы-медных                
                for (var i = 0; i < wordsProductName.Length - 1; i++)
                {

                    try
                    {
                        //string previous = i > 0 ? wordsProductName[i - 1] : null; https:// stackoverflow.com/questions/8175684/get-to-next-element-in-list
                        string currentWord = wordsProductName[i];
                        string nextWord = i < wordsProductName.Count() ? wordsProductName[i + 1] : null;
                        categoryIdsFromProductName = allCategories.Where(c => c.Name.Contains(currentWord)).Select(c => c.Id).ToList(); // отобрали основные категории 
                        categoryIdsFromProductNameChild = AdSearchHelper.ChildCategoriesToAdd(categoryIdsFromProductName, allCategories);//поиск по дочерним категориям от выбранных в фильтре категорий (например выбрали Лом и отходы черных металлов, должны найти объявления со "Стальные")

                        if (nextWord != null)
                        {
                            allCategoriesNext = ProductCategoriesDAL.CategoryTermsSearch(string.Join(" ,", categoryIdsFromProductNameChild)).ToList(); // создали список Категорий Продуктов
                            categoryIdsFromProductNameNext = allCategoriesNext.Where(c => c.Name.Contains(nextWord)).Select(c => c.Id).Distinct().ToList();// поиск по следующему слову == итог == Id Категорий Продуктов
                            categoryIdsFromProductNameNext = AdSearchHelper.ChildCategoriesToAdd(categoryIdsFromProductNameNext, allCategoriesNext); // поиск по дочерним категориям от выбранных в фильтре категорий (например выбрали Лом и отходы черных металлов, должны найти объявления со "Стальные")
                            adsAdCategory = AdsDAL.GetAdsForSearchPage(adStatusId: null, categoriesId: categoryIdsFromProductNameNext, townIds, isBuy, productName: null, (int)ModerateResults.Accepted).ToList(); // List<Ad> == вытаскиваем все по категориям
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (categoryIdsFromProductNameChild.Any())
                            {
                                if (categoryIds == null)
                                    categoryIds = new List<int>();
                                categoryIds.AddRange(categoryIdsFromProductNameChild);
                            }
                            //#region  поиск по дочерним категориям от выбранных в фильтре категорий (например выбрали Лом и отходы черных металлов, должны найти объявления со "Стальные")
                            //categoryIds = AdSearchHelper.ChildCategoriesToAdd(categoryIds, allCategories);
                            //#endregion
                            adsAdCategory = AdsDAL.GetAdsForSearchPage(adStatusId: null, categoriesId: categoryIds, townIds, isBuy, productName: null, (int)ModerateResults.Accepted).ToList(); // List<Ad> == вытаскиваем все по категориям

                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        string expp = ex.Message;
                    }
                }
                #endregion

                #region Search в словосочетании с дефисом То есть он выдаст только те варианты где словосочетание указано целиком в Полном наименовании товара == то есть по таблице AdProduct поле Name
                List<Ad> wordAdsAdProductName = new List<Ad>(); // список объявлений с учетом поиска по словам из словосочетания
                for (var i = 0; i < wordsProductName.Length - 1; i++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // лом-отходы-медных
                        //string previous = i > 0 ? wordsProductName[i - 1] : null; https:// stackoverflow.com/questions/8175684/get-to-next-element-in-list
                        string current = wordsProductName[i];
                        string next = i < wordsProductName.Count() ? wordsProductName[i + 1] : null;
                        wordAdsAdProductName = AdsDAL.GetAdsForSearchPage(adStatusId: null, categoriesId: null, townIds, isBuy, current.ToLower(), (int)ModerateResults.Accepted).ToList(); // List<Ad> == вытаскиваем все по Наименованию
                        if (next != null)
                        {
                            List<int> idSAd = wordAdsAdProductName.Select(w => w.Id).ToList();
                            List<int> adidS = new List<int>();
                            foreach (int idAd in idSAd)
                            {
                                int adid = AdProductsDAL.GetAdIds(idAd, next);
                                if (adid > 0)
                                    adidS.Add(adid);
                            }
                            List<int> _adidS = adidS.Distinct().ToList();
                            adsAdProductName = AdsDAL.GetAds(null, null, null, null, ids: _adidS, null, null, null, null);
                            LogsDAL.AddMessage(Convert.ToString(string.Join(" ,adid=", _adidS)));
                        }
                        else
                            adsAdProductName = wordAdsAdProductName;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        string expp = ex.Message;
                    }
                }
                #endregion
            }
            else
            {
                #region Search !productName.Contains('-') А для случая когда дефиса нет
                wordsProductName = productName.Split(' ');//А для случая когда дефиса нет, алгоритм будет выдавать все подряд, где есть хотя бы любое слово из словосочетания По словосочетаниям:- если дефиса нет, то поиск работает по каждому слову в отдельности
                if (wordsProductName.Length > 1)
                {
                    foreach (var wordProductName in wordsProductName)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            var categoryIdsFromProductName = allCategories.Where(c => c.Name.Contains(wordProductName.TrimAndReduce())).Select(c => c.Id).ToList();
                            if (categoryIdsFromProductName.Any())
                            {
                                if (categoryIds == null)
                                    categoryIds = new List<int>();
                                categoryIds.AddRange(categoryIdsFromProductName);
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            string expp = ex.Message;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (productName.EndsWith("."))// По одному слову: - если точка, то да слово ищется целиком.
                    {
                        int productNameLastIndexOfCharX2E = productName.LastIndexOf('.');//определить находиться ли точка (char '\x2E') в конце слова ==> отходы.;
                        if (productNameLastIndexOfCharX2E == productName.Length - 1)
                            productName = productName.TrimEnd(new char[] { '.' });// и если есть ==> то удалить её ==> отходы
                        try
                        {
                            var categoryIdsFromProductName = allCategories.Where(c => c.Name.Contains(productName.TrimAndReduce())).Select(c => c.Id).ToList();
                            if (categoryIdsFromProductName.Any())
                            {
                                if (categoryIds == null)
                                    categoryIds = new List<int>();
                                categoryIds.AddRange(categoryIdsFromProductName);
                            }
                            adsAdCategory = AdsDAL.GetAdsForSearchPage(adStatusId: null, categoriesId: categoryIds, townIds, isBuy, productName, (int)ModerateResults.Accepted).ToList(); // List<Ad> == вытаскиваем все по категориям
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            string expp = ex.Message;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Запрос в DAL по входным параметрам при необходимости разбираем СТРОКУ на СЛОВА и делаем запрос по ОТдельности для каждого слова 
                        adsAdCategory = AdsDAL.GetAdsForSearchPage(adStatusId: null, categoriesId: categoryIds, townIds, isBuy, productName, (int)ModerateResults.Accepted).ToList(); // List<Ad> == вытаскиваем все по категориям
                        if (adProductName.Contains('-'))
                            adsAdProductName = AdsDAL.GetAdsForSearchPage(adStatusId: null, categoriesId: null, townIds, isBuy, adProductName.Replace('-', ' ').ToLower(), (int)ModerateResults.Accepted).ToList(); // List<Ad> == вытаскиваем все по Наименованию
                        else
                        {
                            wordsAdProductName = adProductName.Split(' ');
                            if (wordsProductName.Length > 1)
                            {
                                foreach (var wordAdProductName in wordsAdProductName)
                                {
                                    var wordAdsAdProductName = AdsDAL.GetAdsForSearchPage(adStatusId: null, categoriesId: null, townIds, isBuy, wordAdProductName.ToLower(), (int)ModerateResults.Accepted).ToList(); // List<Ad> == вытаскиваем все по Наименованию
                                    try
                                    {
                                        if (wordAdsAdProductName.Count != 0)
                                        {
                                            adsAdProductName = adsAdProductName == null ? wordAdsAdProductName : adsAdProductName.Concat(wordAdsAdProductName).ToList();
                                        }
                                    }
                                    catch (Exception ex)
                                    {
                                        string expp = ex.Message;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (productName.EndsWith(".")) // По одному слову == если точка, то да слово ищется целиком.
                                {
                                    try
                                    {
                                        int productNameLastIndexOfCharX2E = productName.LastIndexOf('.');//определить находиться ли точка (char '\x2E') в конце слова ==> отходы.;
                                        if (productNameLastIndexOfCharX2E == productName.Length - 1)
                                            productName = productName.TrimEnd(new char[] { '.' });// и если есть ==> то удалить её ==> отходы
                                        var wordAdsAdProductName = AdsDAL.GetAdsForSearchPage(adStatusId: null, categoriesId: null, townIds, isBuy, productName.ToLower(), (int)ModerateResults.Accepted).ToList(); // List<Ad> == вытаскиваем все по Наименованию
                                        adsAdProductName = adsAdProductName == null ? wordAdsAdProductName : adsAdProductName.Concat(wordAdsAdProductName).ToList();
                                    }
                                    catch (Exception ex)
                                    {
                                        string expp = ex.Message;
                                    }
                                }
                                else // По одному слову - если точки нет, то да поиск работает по корню
                                {
                                    try
                                    {
                                        string vowel = "аеёиоуыьэюя";
                                        string consonant = "бвгджзйклмнпрстфхцчшщ";
                                        string[] vowels = { "а", "е", "ё", "и", "о", "у", "ы", "ь", "э", "ю", "я" };
                                        string[] consonants = { "б", "в", "г", "д", "ж", "з", "й", "к", "л", "м", "н", "п", "р", "с", "т", "ф", "х", "ц", "ч", "ш", "щ" };
                                        string[] nounsEndings = { "а", "е", "ё", "и", "о", "у", "ы", "ь", "э", "ю", "я" };
                                        string[] adjectivesEndings = { "ой", " ий", " ый", " ая", " яя", " ое", " ее", " ого", " его", " ой", " ей", " ому", " ему", " ой", " ей", " ой", " ий", " ый", " ую", " юю", " ое", " ее", " ого", " его", "ой", "ей" };
                                        string[] lastThreeCharactersEndings = { "ого", "его", "ому", "ему" };
                                        var countLettrWord = productName.Length;// длинна слова
                                        char lastCharacter = productName[productName.Length - 1];//Получение последнего символа
                                        char secondToLastCharacter = productName[productName.Length - 2];//Получение предпоследнего символа
                                        var lastThreeCharacters = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(productName, @"(.{3})\s*$"); // //Получение трёх последних символов
                                        bool _productNameLastThreeCharacters = false; // bool переменная наличия окончания  "ого", "его", "ому", "ему"
                                        string productNameLastThreeCharacter = ""; // новое значение слова поиска Без  окончания  "ого", "его", "ому", "ему"
                                        foreach (string lastThreeCharactersEnding in lastThreeCharactersEndings)
                                        {
                                            if (productName.EndsWith(Convert.ToString(lastThreeCharactersEnding)))
                                            {
                                                _productNameLastThreeCharacters = true;
                                                productNameLastThreeCharacter = WordHelper.CutTextByWord(productName, Convert.ToString(lastThreeCharactersEnding));
                                            }
                                        }
                                        if (vowel.Contains(lastCharacter) && consonant.Contains(secondToLastCharacter) && !_productNameLastThreeCharacters)
                                        {
                                            productName = productName.Substring(0, productName.Length - 1);
                                        }
                                        else if (_productNameLastThreeCharacters)
                                        {
                                            productName = productNameLastThreeCharacter;
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            foreach (var adjectivesEnding in adjectivesEndings)
                                            {
                                                productName = WordHelper.CutTextByWord(productName, adjectivesEnding);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    catch (Exception ex)
                                    {
                                        string expp = ex.Message;
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
                #endregion
            }

            if (adsAdCategory == null)
                ads = adsAdProductName;

            if (adsAdProductName == null)
                ads = adsAdCategory;

            if (adsAdCategory != null && adsAdProductName != null)
                ads = adsAdCategory.Concat(adsAdProductName).ToList();
        }
        else
            ads = AdsDAL.GetAdsForSearchPage(adStatusId: null, categoriesId: categoryIds, townIds, isBuy, productName: null, (int)ModerateResults.Accepted).ToList(); // List<Ad> == вытаскиваем все по категориям

        var adIds = ads.Select(a => a.Id).Distinct().ToList();
        ads = ads
            .GroupBy(a => a.Id).Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault())
            .OrderByDescending(a => a.DateOfPosting).ToList();

        var adsToShow = ads.Skip(((page ?? 1) - 1) * 1000/*C.ItemsPerPageAds// 20221130 krakoss*/).Take(1000/*C.ItemsPerPageAds// 20221130 krakoss*/).ToList();
        viewModel.Ads = AdHelper.GetAdsForView(currentUserId, ads: adsToShow, needInvitedUserIds: true, needSender: true);
        viewModel.AdsCount = ads.Count();

        //Заполнение UrlForAdsIndex, OnClickJsScript
        AdHelper.FillUrlForAdsIndexAndOnClickJsScript(viewModel.Ads);

        #region Нумерация страниц

        var url = Urls.Ads;

        if (isBuy.HasValue)
            url += "?isBuy=" + isBuy.ToString().ToLower();

        if (selectedCategoryIds != null)
            url += (url.Contains("?") ? "&" : "?") + "selectedCategoryIds=" + selectedCategoryIds;

        if (selectedTownIds != null)
            url += (url.Contains("?") ? "&" : "?") + "selectedTownIds=" + selectedTownIds;

        if (selectedRegionIds != null)
            url += (url.Contains("?") ? "&" : "?") + "selectedRegionIds=" + selectedRegionIds;

        if (ViewBag.L.ProductName != null)
            url += (url.Contains("?") ? "&" : "?") + "productName=" + ViewBag.L.ProductName;

        viewModel.PaginationViewModel = new PaginationViewModel(page, ads.Count(), url, 1000/*C.ItemsPerPageAds// 20221130 krakoss*/);

        #endregion

        #region Заполнение заголовка
        var heading = "";
        var headingSearchTerms = "";

        if (isBuy == true)
            heading += "Закупки";
        else if (isBuy == false)
            heading += "Продажи";
        else
            heading += "Все объявления";
        viewModel.Heading = heading;

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(selectedRegionIds))
        {
            var _region = selectedRegionIds.Split(',').Count() > 1 ? "Регионы: " : "Регион: ";
            headingSearchTerms += _region;
            var selectedRegion = RegionsDAL.RegionTermsSearch(selectedRegionIds);
            foreach (var region in selectedRegion)
            {
                headingSearchTerms += region.Name + "; ";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            headingSearchTerms += "Регион: Россия";
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(selectedTownIds))
        {
            var _town = selectedTownIds.Split(',').Count() > 1 ? "Города: " : "Город: ";
            headingSearchTerms += "<br>" + _town;
            var selectedTown = TownsDAL.TownTermsSearch(selectedTownIds);
            foreach (var town in selectedTown)
            {
                headingSearchTerms += town.Name + "; ";
            }
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(selectedCategoryIds))
        {
            var _categoriy = selectedCategoryIds.Split(',').Count() > 1 ? "Категории: " : "Категория: ";
            headingSearchTerms += "<br>" + _categoriy;
            var selectedCategory = ProductCategoriesDAL.CategoryTermsSearch(selectedCategoryIds);
            foreach (var product in selectedCategory)
            {
                headingSearchTerms += product.Name + "; ";
            }
        }
        viewModel.HeadingSearchTerms = headingSearchTerms;
        #endregion

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

как вот в этой строке кода

```
for (var i = 0; i < wordsProductName.Length - 1; i++)
```

реализовать поиск на основе уже имеющего результата
для реализации такого поиска надо использовать следующие знания из этого источника
[Пересечение двух списков в C#](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/intersect-two-lists-in-chash)

в итоге вот небольшой фрагмент кода

```
   #region Search в Названии Категорий товара по таблице ProductCategory поле Name => лом-отходы-медных
        try
        {
            bool allWord = true;
            IEnumerable<int> resСategoryNameIds = null;
            foreach (string word in wordsProductName)
            {
                var categoryNameIds = ProductCategoriesDAL.SearchCategoriesRegex(word, allWord: allWord).Select(c => c.Id).ToList();
                if (categoryNameIds.Any() && categoryNameIds.Count() > 0)
                {
                    if (resСategoryNameIds == null)
                        resСategoryNameIds = categoryNameIds;
                    else
                        resСategoryNameIds = categoryNameIds.AsQueryable().Intersect(resСategoryNameIds);  //IEnumerable<int> res = val1.AsQueryable().Intersect(val2);
                }
            }
            int countRes = resСategoryNameIds.Count();

            adsAdCategory = AdsDAL.GetAdsForSearchPageWordAndIdS(categoriesId: resСategoryNameIds.ToList(), adStatusId: null, townIds, isBuy, (int)ModerateResults.Accepted).ToList(); // List<Ad> == вытаскиваем все по категориям
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string expp = ex.Message;
            LogsDAL.AddError(expp);
        }
        #endregion
```

Comment: А что не получается ?

Comment: Да показывайте код, без этого вопрос могут быстренько закрыть

Comment: использование List<int> вместо var - это для того чтобы не перепутать что и как

Comment: Вы лучше вопрос дополняйте, чтобы всё в одном месте было

Comment: Вопрос не имеет отношения к asp.net, поэтому нерелевантную метку следует удалить. / Поиск и пересечение крайне желательно осуществлять в базе данных, чтобы не тянуть из неё лишние данные. Как правильно это сделать? Опишите, как выполняете запросы в БД. Сейчас в коде видно только методы репозитория и что скрывается за ними нам неизвестно. / Нам даже неизвестно, какого типа БД используется: реляционка или nosql.

Answer (score -1):

знания полученные из этого источника
[Пересечение двух списков в C#](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/intersect-two-lists-in-chash)

помогли решить эту задачу

Теперь используйте метод Intersect(), чтобы получить пересечение двух списков.

IEnumerable res = val1.AsQueryable().Intersect(val2);

Comment: я думаю что да поймут. Готовый код я уже приложил

Comment: Сюда поместите ответ, удалив его из вопроса.